Determine all $(m, n, p)$ satisfying the conditions
Find all triples of positive integers $(m, n, p)$ such that $p$ is a prime number and there exist positive integers $a$ and $b$ for which the following holds: $mn + 1 = p^a$,$m + n = p^b$.
I got this problem from my number theory class from a few weeks ago. So far, here's my progres:
Approach $1$. From the second equation, we get
$$m=p^b-n$$
Plugging this in in the first equation we get
\begin{align*}
n(p^b-n)+1&=p^a\\
n^2-p^bn+p^a-1&=0
\end{align*}
This is a quadratic in $n$, so the discriminant is
$$D=p^{2b}-4p^a+4$$
That's where I got stuck.
Approach $2$. From the second equation we get
$$m+n\equiv0\pmod p\implies m\equiv-n\pmod p$$
We write $m=px+z,n=py-z$. Plugging this in to the first equation we get
\begin{align*}
(px+z)(py-z)+1&=p^a\\
p^2xy-pxz+pyz-z^2+1&=p^a
\end{align*}
From this we get $z^2\equiv1\pmod p$, so I thought using orders, but I have no Idea what or how to do it. Are these approaches any help?

Since $n$ is natural, the discriminant has to be $0$. This should give you that $p=2$.

Doesn't the discriminant only have to be a perfect square?

Ah yes, my bad. I jumped the gun a little.

As far as you know, do "natural numbers" here include $0$ or not?

It's positive integers, let's put it that way.

I deleted my comment when I saw the mistake is actually in the next line with your discriminant. Since for $ax^2+bx+c=0$ it's $D=b^2-4ac$, you should have got $D=p^{2b}-4p^a+4$ instead. This is a reason why there are additional solutions, as anankEpis' comment indicates.

Ohh, yes you're right. My bad, I'll fix it right away

You've made a good start, but I unfortunately don't offhand know how to use either of your approaches to get a solution. Instead, here's an alternate method. We have the $2$ equations of
$$mn + 1 = p^a, \;\; m + n = p^b$$
First, if $m = 1$, then $n + 1 = p^a = p^b$, and similarly if $n = 1$ instead. Thus, there are the solutions of $\lbrace (1, p^a - 1, p), (p^a - 1, 1, p)\rbrace$ for all primes $p$ and positive integers $a$.
Thus, consider only where $m \gt 1$ and $n \gt 1$. Subtracting the second equation from the first one gives
$$mn - m - n + 1 = p^a - p^b \;\;\to\;\; (m - 1)(n - 1) = p^b(p^{a-b} - 1)$$
Thus, $p \mid m - 1$ and/or $p \mid n - 1$. Since $m + n = p^b$ then, if both were true, we'd have $2\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. Thus, for odd primes $p$, just one of them occurs, say WLOG that $p \mid m - 1$ only. We then have
$$p^b \mid m - 1 \;\;\to\;\; m = jp^b + 1, \;\; j \in \mathbb{N^{+}}$$
However, then $m \gt p^b$, which means from $m + n = p^b$ that $n \lt 0$, which is not possible. Thus, there are no solutions for odd primes $p$.

Next, consider $p = 2$. In this case, both $m$ and $n$ must be odd, so $2\mid m - 1$ and $2\mid n - 1$. From $(m - 1)(n - 1) = p^b(p^{a-b} - 1)$ stated earlier, we thus have
$$m = 2^{i_1}k_1 + 1, \;\; n = 2^{i_2}k_2 + 1, \;\; i_1 \ge 1,\, i_2 \ge 1,\, i_1 + i_2 = b$$
where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are odd, positive integers. This then gives
$$(2^{i_1}k_1 + 1) + (2^{i_2}k_2 + 1) = 2^b \;\;\to\;\; 2^{i_1}k_1 + 2^{i_2}k_2 + 2 = 2^b$$
If $i_1 \gt 1$ and $i_2 \gt 1$, then the LHS has only $1$ factor of $2$, but $b \ge 3$. This means one of $i_1$ and $i_2$ must be $1$, say WLOG that it's $i_1$, so then $i_2 = b - 1$. However, if $k_2 \gt 1$, then the LHS of the above equation is $\gt 2^b$, so we must have $k_2 = 1$, i.e., $n = 2^{b-1} + 1$. Therefore,
$$2k_1 + 2^{b-1} + 2 = 2^b \;\;\to\;\; m = 2k_1 + 1 = 2^{b-1} - 1$$
Handling also where $m$ and $n$ are switched around, we have just the additional solutions of $\lbrace (2^{b-1} - 1, 2^{b-1} + 1, 2), (2^{b-1} + 1, 2^{b-1} - 1, 2)\rbrace$ for all integers $b \ge 3$.
